# MYSQL how to get single row of policy for each customer by last date

Tags: php, mysql

i have two table

vehicle_data

```
 id chassis name      number
  1 00001   customer1 123456
  2 00002   customer2 654321
  3 00003   customer3 645421
```

insurance_data

```
 id chassis policy_number expiry_date
  1 00001           11111 22-01-2015
  2 00002           22222 22-01-2015
  3 00003           33333 22-01-2015
  4 00001           44444 22-01-2016
  5 00002           55555 22-01-2017
  6 00001           66666 22-01-2017
```

what i want

```
 chassis name      policy_number expiry_date
   00001 customer1         66666 22-01-2017
   00002 customer2         55555 22-01-2017
   00003 customer3         33333 22-01-2015
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this:  "i want only last expiry date policy of all customers using month filter".

Comment: Please consider making an [edit] to your question showing the results you need. You've done a good job showing example data.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you intend:

```
select id.*
from insurance_data id
where id.expiry_date = (select max(id2.expiry_date)
                        from insurance_data id2
                        where id.name = id2.name and
                              month(id2.expiry_date) = 1 
                       );
```

This returns the most recent row in the table for each `name` for the given month of expiry.

Comment: i have updated question , request you to reanswer according to updated question

Comment: Can we achive same in mongodb ?

Comment: @UTKARSHANAND . . . You should ask a *new* question about MongoDB.  The data structures are different, so you should be clear about what the data looks like.